# how to find number of images from file name?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

i need to know how meny image's i have from the file name exp:
i have images call: 
first file:
Splash_10001.jpg
last file:
Splash_10098.jpg
and i want to inset then to array..

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%04d.%@",self.firstImageName,i,self.imageType]];
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    [imgArray addObject:image];
}
```

i want to replace IMAGE_COUNT with number 98 but i need to get the numbre from the string the user send me : Splash_10098.jpg
i need to Separate the Splash_10098.jpg into: nsstring:Splash_1  int:0098  nsstring:jpg
10x all!

Comment: Can you please accept it, if it helped you. :) There is a tick mark next to the answer. That should help the other folks who are trying to find answer for similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what input are of the string is granted. In the following I would search for the dot and go backwards to the maximum of digits. 
By the way I could only recommend to use the multi lingual NumberFormatter instead of relying on the default conversion.

```
  NSString * input = @"Splash_19001.jpg";
  NSRange r = [input rangeOfString:@"."];
  if(r.location>4){
    NSString * numberPart = [input substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(r.location-4,4)];
    NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber * number = [nf numberFromString:numberPart];
    int val = [number intValue];
    NSLog(@"intValue=%d",val);
  }
```

Comment: It should not be delimited, only the four digits, thus 9999+1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
NSString *stringUserSendsYou = @"Splash_10098.jpg";
int IMAGE_COUNT = [[[stringUserSendsYou stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Splash_1" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".jpg" withString:@""] integerValue];
```

Comment: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]` would be more efficient.

Comment: That would return 10098, right? I think he wants it as 0098 alone. The problem with above approach is that it assumes Splash_1 as the prefix string always. I am not sure if that is the requirement.

Comment: you right the Splash_1 is not constant can be change from app to app

Comment: the Splash_1 is just exp.. i need some code that will give me the 0098

Comment: @Sosily, Check my answer. It should dynamically give any string based on regex.

Answer (score 0):

If the number length is fixed in the suffix, it would make sense to use a substring instead of trying to remove the prefix. Strip the extension and grab the last x characters, convert those into an int with either `intValue` or the `NSNumberFormatter` suggested by iOS, although that might be unnecessary if you are sure of the format of the string.

```
NSString *userProvidedString = @"Splash_10001.jpg";
NSString *numberString = [userProvidedString stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSUInteger length = [numberString length];
NSInteger numberLength = 4;
if (length < numberLength)
{
     NSLog(@"Error in the string");
     return;
}
numberString = [numberString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(length - 4, 4)];
NSInteger integer = [numberString integerValue];
// Do whatever you want with the integer.
```

Comment: Sorry for posting, but I haven't seen your answer. Despite the NumberFormatter basically identically. Btw, interesting method "stringByDeletingPathExtension" I did not stumble over this method before.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Regex`(`NSRegularExpression` in iOS), this can be done very easily,

Check this out,

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSString *originalString = @"Splash_10098.jpg";
NSString *regexString = @"([^\?]*_[0-9])([0-9]*)(.)([a-z]*)";

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:originalString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive range:NSMakeRange(0, [originalString length])];

NSLog(@"FileName: %@", [originalString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
NSLog(@"Total Count: %@", [originalString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]]);
NSLog(@"File type: %@", [originalString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:4]]);
```

**Result:**

```
FileName: Splash_1
Total Count: 0098
File type: jpg
```